# Set margin of skewed <section>

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skew

I just skewed a section which is serving as a banner.

Now this section takes a higher height than expected obviously because of the skew.

How can I define my bottom margin based on this new height?

```css
.banner{
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
    outline: solid 1px black;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</section>
<div class="content">
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

If you open the snippet in full screen and change the window size you know what I mean... The content just gets hidden behind the banner.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663430/css-transform-math-calculate-height-of-div-caused-by-skew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, size is changing based on width so update margin based on width, for that you can use [unit `vw`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#vw).

```css
.banner{
    transform: skewY(-5deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
    outline: solid 1px black;
    margin-bottom: 9vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</section>
<div class="content">
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this works like a charm! Did not know that vw even existed! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also skew `.content` with the same transformation and then unskew the content inside:

```css
.banner {
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  outline: solid 1px black;
}

.content {
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin: right;
}

.content p {
  transform: skewY(5deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</section>
<div class="content">
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works too.. But I prefere vw as shown in the answer above! Thanks a lot!